# Curl request is working fine in terminal but not working in python after converting

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a curl request that gets me the '200' response on terminal but when I convert it to python using 'https://curl.trillworks.com/' and send python request using terminal I'm getting '403' as a response.

Curl Request

```
curl 'https://www.realestate.com.au/agent/graphql' --data-binary $'{"operationName":"SendEnquiry","variables":{"enquiry":{"id":"1375705","enquiryType":"General enquiry","propertyAddress":"","message":"Australia property prices?","contactMethod":"EMAIL","name":"sadfal","phone":"","email":"ahmadarshi@ucp.edu.pk","sourceUrl":"https://www.realestate.com.au/agent/mary-wang-1375705","referrer":""}},"query":"mutation SendEnquiry($enquiry: ConsumerEnquiryInput\u21) {\\n  sendEnquiry(enquiry: $enquiry) {\\n    status\\n    isValid\\n    message\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n}\\n"}' --compressed
```

Python Request

```
import requests

data = '${"operationName":"SendEnquiry","variables":{"enquiry":{"id":"1375705","enquiryType":"General enquiry","propertyAddress":"","message":"Australia property prices?","contactMethod":"EMAIL","name":"sadfal","phone":"","email":"ahmadarshi@ucp.edu.pk","sourceUrl":"https://www.realestate.com.au/agent/mary-wang-1375705","referrer":""}},"query":"mutation SendEnquiry($enquiry: ConsumerEnquiryInput\\u21) {\\\\n  sendEnquiry(enquiry: $enquiry) {\\\\n    status\\\\n    isValid\\\\n    message\\\\n    __typename\\\\n  }\\\\n}\\\\n"}'

response = requests.post('https://www.realestate.com.au/agent/graphql', data=data)
```

Comment: try using ```data=json.dumps(data)``` in post method

Comment: and you can use postman request converter to convert HTTP request in python code.

Comment: No, response is still 403

Comment: Perhaps give us the original url and query you are using that generated this curl

Answer (score 0):

403 means that the request is denied (you are forbidden to access the page). Make sure that you validate with the API documentation what headers are required for the request and potentially what `Content-Type` needs to be specified along with the data.

Also, it seems that you might be malforming the request - the `$` should likely be excluded from the string.

Comment: It is working fine with curl req even though I have not included the headers.

Comment: cURL automatically appends some of the headers depending on the request being processed - you can try intercepting that with `curl -v` to see what is being sent out, and then mimic that in your request.

Comment: That's a very handy tip. but I'm new to scrapy and can't find out what are my required fields. Could you please me? I'm being stuck at it for hours now

Comment: Couple of things here: (1) if you are not supposed to be accessing the page, then we can't help you get there. (2) see what cURL outputs in the request (if you know it was successful, and then specify the same headers and content formatting in your `requests`-based implementation. It's hard to help without seeing what you've tried to address the core issue after initial guidance was provided.

Comment: I understand Sir, and I really appreciate your guidance. I am just making the same curl request as mentioned above in question. along with curl -v 'https://www.realestate.com.au/agent/graphql' --data-b....

Answer (score 0):

it appears to be a bug in the https://curl.trillworks.com/ bash parser - the $ is not passed to curl and is not part of data to be posted. i'd send a bugreport to the trillworks guys if i were you. quoting http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes :

> $'...' : This is a Bash extension. It prevents everything except backslash escaping, and also allows special backslash escape sequences like \n for newline, \t for tab, and \xnn for bytes specified in hexadecimal.

and the curl.trillworks.com parser incorrectly parses the $'...' syntax.